# Is it possible to specify dynamic range in auto filter syntax?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have written below code to apply auto filter. Code is working fine. However I have specified static range, here: `*Range("A1", **"M"** & lastRow).AutoFilter*` .
Is there a way to replace `"M"` with last existing column number in sheet2.
I have calculated last existing column `*myCol = rngFound.Column - 1*`. But not sure how to use it.
Please help !!!

My Code:

```
Sub testfilter1()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myCol As Long
Dim rngFound As Range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Activate

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngFound = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            myCol = rngFound.Column - 1 ' this will give last used column

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "M" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*somename*"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Cells()` within `Range()`:

```
...Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lastRow,myCol))...
```

`Cells(1,1)` is the cell `A1`.  The format is `Cells([row],[column])`

Edit: Just realized you could also use `Range("A1",Cells(lastRow,myCol))`.  Personally, if I use `Cells()` I do it in both places in `Range()`, but that's personal preference and this other way should work for you too.